# How to deny VNC access to a particular IP?

Tags: vnc

I just want to deny VNC access to particular IP addresses. Is it possible? If yes how to acheive this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generic answer for any service:

```
sudo ufw deny from <IP> to port <PORT>
```

You'll need to turn on `ufw` (`sudo ufw enable`) but it'll let you do this.

Comment: Very nice way of putting it.